# Apache Spark exception handling

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working with Apache Spark and I would like to now more about exception handling.

My situation is that I have a quite complex process, and at the end I do an action.

Obviously, I need to handle exception in the middle of process, so just at the end, so basically also when I do transformation like map, flatMap, etc...

How would I go about handling exceptions? Tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is use Try

```
    rdd.map({
    Try(fn) match{
case Success: _
case Failure:<<Record with error flag>>
}).filter(record.errorflag==null)
```

Unfortunately there is no easier way to do this with DataFrame/Set API. There should be a way push exception handlers in all dataframe operations like select, group by etc. To handle data related errors gracefully during the pipeline.
See this [Row level exception handling in Apache Spark DataFrame/Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804910/row-level-exception-handling-in-apache-spark-dataframe-set)